# making non-static http links

Tags: php, http

i am currently trying to add a file directory into a http so that the http link will not be static to a single computer.

I tried to input getcwd() into the http link but it does work.

is there any way to make a non-static http link ?

for example this is my old link :

```
$link="http://qna.nyp.edu.sg/qa4u/qa4u_working/presenter/eventfile/EventID".$eid."/".$eid."_".$email.".pdf";
```

I am trying to do this instead :

```
$link="http:\\".getcwd()."\\eventfile\\EventID".$eid."\\".$eid."_".$email.".pdf";
```

is it possible to make it work?

Comment: have a look at the available $_SERVER vars

Answer (score 0):

use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

```
$link="http:\\".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."\\eventfile\\EventID".$eid."\\".$eid."_".$email.".pdf";
```